# Adding column value in another table in sas

Tags: sql, sas

I have this table called A and it has id and have another table called B having blank id column.I want to add these id from table A to B .Suppose first it will add ID 1 in table B then ID 2 3 4 5 so on .. whenever i add  value to table A it automatically gets add into the table B with time of 3 min .means table B will be refreshed by 3 min and fetch record from table A.But you have to check previous record value in table B and then add next value

```
--------------
|      ID      |
---------------
|       1      |
|       2      |
|       3      |
|       4      |
|       5      |
|       6      |
|       7      |
|       8      |
|       9      |
|       10     |
----------------
```

Comment: I don't know about SAS, but this sounds like the job for some sort of insertion trigger.

Comment: yes any idea using trigger

Comment: Are A and B SAS data sets ?  How are values getting added to A ? A SAS server stored process ? SAS is not a RDBMS that implements triggers at a row write level.   If the updates to table A and B are through carefully managed actors (i.e. all changes happen through the use of a common macro or stored process) it can be possible to emulate trigger behavior.

Comment: sas dataset A has ID column which is incremental bt when i update dataset A with new ID it should add those new values in Dataset B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS data sets (tables) are not the same as Relational database tables so you can't add triggers on SAS tables. But you can schedule a sas program to run every 3 mins. to copy new values from table A to table B. Example code below.

**Steps:**

1. Create data for tables A & B
2. Create Lookup table with distinct IDs from B
3. Insert in B new IDs which are not in Lookup table (SAS will have table lock if I was reading and inserting data into same table (B); that's why I have the lookup table)

**Code:**

```
data a;
input id;
datalines;
1
2
3
4
5
;
run;
data b;
input id;
datalines;
1
2
;
run;

proc sql;
create table lookup as select distinct id from b; quit;

proc sql;
 insert into work.b select * from a where a.id not in (select id from lookup) ;
quit;
```

**Output: Table B post insert**

```
id=1 
id=2 
id=3 
id=4 
id=5
```

Comment: legends are real @momo1644